# Formula for finding bold text and returning yes or no

Tags: google-sheets

As stated in the title.

Im working on a spreadsheet, optimising it for collecting (or rather to index a collection).

The spreadsheet looks like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SyKB6YSEHVXIl-aYAEXxtcJ3Spm92XPPsHHhRprEurM/edit#gid=0

What i need is a piece of code which automaticly sets the "owned" boxes to yes or no, depending on if any one of the cells, lef tside of said "owned"-box, under Title:, Appears in: or Season Collections: contains bold text. (see that way you can just locate the collectible you've bought and bold it. Yeah, i know i can just manually type in the yes's and no's. But i like trying to find solutions in code even though i know pretty much nothing on the subject, it's a challange).

I've been googlin' for a solution. Found some promesing stuff on this site. However, i can't get them darn lines of code to work.

```
    function ifBold() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Bold');
  var cells = sheet.getRange('A2:A');
  for (var i=1; i <= cells.getNumRows(); i++) {
    var isBold = false;
    if(cells.getCell(i, 1).getFontWeight() == 'bold')
      isBold = true;
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(isBold);
  }
}
```

What say ya'? Help a clueless novice out?

I guess the code above only applies to numbers?

This one might be more usefull. Still can't get it to work though.

```
function ifBold(rangeSpecification) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Bold');
  var cells = sheet.getRange('rangeSpecification');
  for (var i=1; i <= cells.getNumRows(); i++) {
    var isBold = false;
    if(cells.getCell(i, 1).getFontWeight() == 'bold')
      isBold = true;
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(isBold);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=ifBold(A1:C1)` will not work since it is grabbing the values as an array and not the range notation.
You will need to change it to `=ifBold("A1:C1")` for it to work.

Also, I have some edits to make this work better for you:

```
function ifBold(rangeSpecification) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification);
  var weights = range.getFontWeights();

  for (var i in weights[0]) {
    var isBold = false;
    if(weights[0][i].toString() == "bold"){
      isBold = true;
      return isBold;
    }
  }
  return isBold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried it out and, yeah, that sure works.

However, it only seems to work if the range is one single cell. When i add the three cell range i wan't it just goes false no matter what.

And there's this update issue as well. I'f the function is in place before any cell is bold or vice versa, it dosn't update.

Edit: Tried to at least vote up your ansver. But my user isn't cool enough to do that yet. Anyways, thank you again!

Edit again: I have to correct myself. It seems the code is only grabbing the first cell in the line if there is more then one cell!

Comment: I just noticed my mistake. I have updated it. The fix is weights[0] and moving a return outside of the for loop.

Comment: That did it! Works as a charm! Thanks a bunch and more!